# SQl Left Join with tables

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I have two tables -
Table 1: `Types`

```
ID | Type
---+------
1  | type1
2  | type2
3  | type3
4  | type4
5  | type5
6  | type6
```

Table 2: `Details`

```
ID | Type   | EventName | Cost
---+--------+-----------+------
1  | type1  | name1     | 500
2  | type1  | name2     | 500
3  | type2  | name3     | 500
4  | type3  | name4     | 1500
5  | type3  | name5     | 1000
6  | type3  | name6     | 1000
```

Expected result from two tables:

```
Type   | Number | Cost
-------+--------+--------------
type1  | 2      | 1000
type2  | 1      | 500
type3  | 3      | 3500
type4  | 0      | 0
type5  | 0      | 0
type6  | 0      | 0
```

I tried with `LEFT JOIN`. But it does not give me the right numbers.

Comment: use count(eventName), sum(cost) as agg functions and group by type.

Comment: what is the number field?

Comment: Number field is the COUNT of  entries.

Comment: @SyedSohailAhmed i updated my query and its working fine.please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT t.Type, count(d.Type), sum(d.cost) 
FROM Types t LEFT JOIN Details d ON t.Type=d.Type
group by t.Type,d.Type
```

Comment: This gives an error.....
Column 'd.type' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: you forgot to group by type, the non-aggregated column

Comment: @SyedSohailAhmed i executed the above query of mine in mysql and its working fine as per your requirement.please check

Comment: Thank you so much.. I tried the group by before.. but I think I was not referencing to right columns in ON clause of joins.... anyways your answer helped a lot..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  t.Type, 
  count(t.type) as Number, 
  sum(d.cost) as Cost 
FROM 
  Types t 
  INNER JOIN Details d 
     ON t.type=d.type 
  GROUP BY t.type
```

Comment: count should be over d.type to show 0 entries for not used types

Answer (score -1):

Try SELECT *
FROM (t.type), (t.EventName)
WHERE sum(d.cost)

Comment: lolx... I would be so messed up if I had tried this. Sorry @Hex .. i think you should take a look at my question again...